# Getting null value from ajax form submission

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

When I submit the from , I am getting null value from the form using ajax, In current situation I do have 3 fields, I am not getting any values from the form, 
Please help me to find out the solution.

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-centered m-0 table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sl</th>
      <th style="width:10%;">name</th>
      <th>email</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="purchaseData">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="name" placeholder="name" required=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="costPrice" name="email" placeholder="500" required=""></td>
      <td><input type="date" class="form-control" id="costPrice" name="email" placeholder="email" required=""></td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary item-edit" id="btnSave">Submit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="name" placeholder="name" required=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="costPrice" name="email" placeholder="500" required=""></td>
      <td><input type="date" class="form-control" id="costPrice" name="date" required=""></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary item-edit" id="btnSave">Submit</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#purchaseData').on('click', '.item-edit', function() {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr")
    var name = row.find("[name=name]").val();
    var email = row.find("[name=email]").val();
    var date = row.find("[name=date]").val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo site_url('Con_test/add_purchase_for_shop')?>",
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: {
        'name': name,
        'email': email,
        'date': date
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if (data == '1') {
          var btn = $(this).closest("tr")
          var name = inputData.find("button").prop('disabled', false).css(
            "background-color", "green");
        } else {
          var btn = $(this).closest("tr")
          var name = inputData.find("button").prop('disabled', true).css(
            "background-color", "#2d7bf4");
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: where is `<form>` Tag?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page  You're repeating ids.

Answer (score 0):

your date name is name="email" it should be name="date":

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#purchaseData').on('click', '.item-edit', function(event) {

         event.preventDefault();
         var row = $(this).closest("tr")
         var name = row.find("[name=name]").val();
         var email = row.find("[name=email]").val();
         var date = row.find("[name=date]").val();
         console.log('row ', row)
         console.log('name ', name)
         console.log('email ', email)
         console.log('date ', date)
});
    })
```